# Do any two affine rotations with no common fixed point generate an infinite group?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, geometry, linear-transformations, euclidean-geometry

Assume we have two affine rotations of the plane around two different fixed points. 
Do they generate an infinite group?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I think they do.

Comment: Why? What have you tried to prove this? What leads to you having this intuition?

Comment: @YaniorWeg I don't think it's appropriate to edit a "no effort" question in this way, especially so soon after the question was asked (unless there was some oddity with the "ownership" of the edit?). I'm undoing it for the time being.

Comment: A short question does not mean a "no effort" question, even if it's a "no context" question. It is a sometimes a good point to ask short concise questions and the effort is not necessarily apparent. Distinguishing between standard exercises and original questions (or tricky exercises) can be done by users familiar with the field, but it turns out that many users on this site now close questions they cannot solve only counting the number of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a group $G$ of affine self-transformations of a vector space $V$: then if $G$ is finite then $G$ fixes $\frac1{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}g(0)$.

By contraposition, if $G$ is generated by a subset $S$ and there is no common fixed point for elements of $S$, then $G$ is infinite.

Comment: Do you have a source/proof  for this statement?

Comment: @WilliamBit Have you tried? checking this statement (the first assertion with the formula) is immediate, since affine transformations preserves barycenters.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I worked with another definition for affine transformations and didn't know that we can define affine transformations as the barycenter preserving functions on a vector space.